# Base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'QStandardItemModel'

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qstandarditemmodel

I'm not 100% up to scratch regarding my understanding of pointers.

I have some code that is giving me the following error:

> base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'QStandardItemModel'

Here is the relevant code:

**stocklist.h**

```
class StockList
{
public:
    void populateStockModel();
private:
    QStandardItemModel m_stockModel;
};
```

**stocklist.cpp**

```
void StockList::populateStockModel() {
    foreach(Item* item, m_items) {
        QList<QStandardItem*> newRow;

        QStandardItem* stockID = new QStandardItem(QString("%1").arg(item->stockID()));
        QStandardItem* desc = new QStandardItem(QString("%1").arg(item->stockID()));
        QStandardItem* price = new QStandardItem(QString("%1").arg(item->stockID()));

        newRow.append(stockID);
        newRow.append(desc);
        newRow.append(price);

        m_stockModel->appendRow(newRow);
    }
}
```

The error refers to the line that contains `m_stockModel->appendRow(newRow);`.

Any idea how I can resolve this?  I'm basically trying to populate a model using those item values.

Help would be much appreciate!  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's right there to see - `m_stockModel` is a `QStandardItemModel`, and it doesn't have an `operator->()`.

You probably meant to write `m_stockModel.appendRow()`, or to declare `m_stockModel` as a pointer to `QStandardItemModel`.  Without a full example, it's hard to be sure which.

You probably want to improve your exception-safety too - if allocating `price` fails, you'll leak `stockID` and `desc`.

Answer (score 1):

For `m_stockModel` to be regarded as a pointer, you will need to declare it as such by using the asterisk notation:

```
QStandardItemModel * m_stockModel;
```

You will also need to allocate memory for `m_stockModel` by using the `new` operator before calling its functions.

I recommend studying the basics of [pointers in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)